# How to change schema validation for flutter's pubspec.yaml?

Tags: validation, flutter, yaml, schema, version

When I specify version different from common standard, for example, `version: 0.x.x`, it does not get included into app version info after build and I get schema validation error during other build operations:

```
flutter --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...                    
Error on line 18, column 10 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version number: Could not parse "0.x.x".

   ╷

18 │ version: 0.x.x

   │          ^^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

Also I get a following tooltip: 
`Schema validation: String is violating the pattern: '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:[+-]\S+)?$'` that hints at obligatory regexp format that should be followed by version values.

How could I change pubspec.yaml validation schema in order to allow for versions of custom format?

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue. In pubspec.yaml, I have set app version as :

version: 4.1+41000

Then, I replaced this with the line:
version: 4.1.0+41000

And issue was resolved. It is as per documentation written in pubspec.yaml file,

. # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
followed by an optional build number separated by a +.